# Why do I need to "ground" my guitar pickup to the guitar bridge

Tags: ac, ground, guitar-amplifier

When wiring my guitar pickup, I connected the ground wire to the ground of the output jack. After hooking that up, I would hear a hum unless I soldered a wire from the metal bridge of the guitar (where the strings enter the guitar body) to the same ground of the output jack. Why did I need to connect the bridge to ground?

Answer (score 2):

The 'ground' of the output jack is actually a shield (and probably connected to chassis ground). It prevents outside electric fields (especially the 60Hz hum) from capacitively coupling into the audio signals inside the cable and jack. By soldering the bridge to the shield, you are extending the shield around the pickups.

Noise can couple into circuits capacitively (via electric fields) or inductively (via magnetic fields). Shielding stops electric fields. Its also good not to turn cabling into an antenna (which could have also been happening with your setup.

Magnetic fields are more difficult because they can only be attenuated by materials. The best thing to do is not create loops which make antennas and avoid mutual coupling (every wire with current creates a magnetic field)

An ideal [shield](https://www.electronic.nu/2016/05/30/shielded-cables-their-role-in-reducing-emi-susceptibilty-and-emissions/) looks like the bottom diagram, since you can't put a shield all the way around the pickups, grounding it is a close second.

[image: https://www.electronic.nu/2016/05/30/shielded-cables-their-role-in-reducing-emi-susceptibilty-and-emissions/]

Comment: What do you mean by chassis ground, specifically?

Comment: Chassis ground is the ground in the device connected to mains ground. Usually shields are attached to chassis ground, but not always. And chassis ground isn't always connected to mains ground. In the case of a guitar amp they should be

Answer (score 2):

Point 1 is that your body can pick up a lot of interference including AC power voltages. These are capacitively connected to your body from the wiring in your home. Point 2 is that the strings and bridge form a fairly decent plate of a capacitor. When you touch this "plate" and this "plate" is floating, you are applying your body's received AC voltage to it.

At these fairly low frequencies, the outer metal screen of a guitar pickup (if it has one as per gibson guitars) is not a great shield against the influences received by the body. This means you get another capacitive connectivity to the coils in the pick up.

If the bridge is grounded to the jack, when you touch the strings, the voltage that is picked up by the body is shunted away to local guitar ground and the interference is much reduced.

Gibson guitars are more resilient to this situation because of the more metalized pick up. Fender guitars can be more problematic. This has nothing to do with the use of humbucking pick ups on Gibson guitars; this is an electric field influenced problem.

Comment: uhm, i think the reason Gibson guitars do better than the Fenders is the use of humbucking pickups.  those Strat pickups are single-polarity, not dual-wound humbuckers.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson the hum bucker uses two antiphase coils to reduce magnetic field interference from AC wiring and this isn't what the question is about as far as I can tell.

Comment: 'your body' in point 1 is the human body, not the guitar body, right?

Comment: @codecowboy correct, yes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you do not need to ground the bridge (and it can actually be dangerous to the player if the amp is not correctly grounded), although you will want to properly shield the guitar.

According to "Electric Guitar & Bass Making & Marketing" by Leo Lospennato (2015), he states the following (pg. 220):

> A guitar itself cannot electrocute you; no electrical current comes from it.  But, an unexpected electrical current coming through it (originated in faulty microphone or amplifier, for example), will.  The problem is that many cheap guitars, instead of implementing good shielding simply have their bridges connected to ground....  This is an effective way to avoid hums, but it is sloppy, and dangerous, too.  Since the bridge is connected to ground, so are the strings, and so is... the player.

He suggests that if you do choose to ground the bridge that you use a small 5mA fuse (although acknowledges that "There is a potential setback... though.  When you plug your guitar to an effects box or pedal, the tip of the jack touches the 9 volt battery lead, sending a current through the instrument, and potentially causing the fuse to blow" (pg. 220)).  He suggests a quick replace fuse block, with fuse, for convenience purposes if the fuse option is used.

For proper shielding he recommends (pg. 218 - 220) not connecting the bridge to ground (unless using the 5mA fuse), and shield all cavities, and the inside of the cavity covers, with self adhesive copper shielding foil (the case of the potentiometer connection with the shielding foil will provide the appropriate ground).  To ground the multiple cavities together: "Simply strip one end of a wire and stick it to the cavity using another piece of shielding foil (remember, the glue they use is conductive, so this is enough)."

Here is a [story to illustrate the point](https://music-electronics-forum.com/forum/instrumentation/guitar-tech/41819-taylor-expression-system-es-ii-fused-string-ground?p=602226#post602226)

Just passing that along.

Comment: IMO a guitar that is hooked up to an amp with a standard phone plug doesn't have to assume that the phone plug ring is at live potential. using that same logic you couldn't touch any metal in your home, because it *could be live* if someone stupid enough wired stuff wrongly. You connect device chassis to PE *assuming* that the PE prong of the mains cable is actually PE and not live. That also works well.